# android change color of an icon from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have the following `EditText` :

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_arrow_bottom_right_black_18dp, 0);
```

and I am trying to change the color of `ic_arrow_bottom_right_black_18dp` programatically using the below methods:

```
     protected void setEditTextDisabled(EditText editText) {
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.setClickable(false);
        editText.setEnabled(false);
        editText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.package_components_group_text_color));
        if (editText.getTag(R.id.values_list_selected_ids) == null) {
            if (editText.getTag(R.id.values_list_selected_ids) == null) {
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                Drawable[] d = editText.getCompoundDrawables();
                if (d.length == 4) {
                    d[2].setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.package_components_group_text_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
            }
        }
        Drawable background = editText.getBackground();

        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
//          ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.package_components_group_text_color));
//            ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.package_components_group_text_color));

        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable)background).setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.package_components_group_text_color));
        } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
//            ((ColorDrawable)background).setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.package_components_group_text_color));
        }
    }

    protected void setEditTextEnabled(EditText editText) {
        editText.setEnabled(true);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setClickable(true);
        editText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
        if (editText.getTag(R.id.values_list_selected_ids) == null) {
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            Drawable[] d = editText.getCompoundDrawables();
            if (d.length == 4) {
                  d[2].setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }

        Drawable background = editText.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
         //   ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable)background).setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
          //  ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the drawable right icon of the `EditText` become invisible or white when one of the above methods is called.

I attached a picture [image: a picture] with the icon of the edit text which is located on right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right answer

```
Drawable ddd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_bottom_right_black_18dp);
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ddd);

DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.package_components_group_text_color));

editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of icon not background using Picasso library. If you can get the icon as an ImageView you can do that. Picasso is very simple and most powerful library.

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.your_icon)
            .transform(new ColorTransformation(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)))
            .into(imageViewIcon);
```